# Block based enumeration getting BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, enumeration

I have a block based enumeration setup to go through an array of NSDictionaries like this:

```
__block NSURL *contentURL;

 //This method of enumerating over the array gives the bad_access error
[documents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString *aName = [(NSDictionary *)obj objectForKey:@"Name"];

    if([aName isEqualToString:name]) {

        contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[(NSDictionary *)obj objectForKey:@"Content"]];
        *stop=YES;
    }
}];

NSLog(@"Content URL for issue with name %@ is %@", name, contentURL);
```

Which if I use this method I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on `contentURL` when I try to print it out in the NSLog statement.

If however, I enumerate through the array like this:

```
NSURL *contentURL;

//This method of enumerating over the array works fine
for (NSDictionary *obj in documents) {

    NSString *aName = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];

    if([aName isEqualToString:name]) {

        contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[obj objectForKey:@"Content"]];

    }
}

NSLog(@"Content URL for issue with name %@ is %@", name, contentURL);
```

All works fine. Why is this?

Comment: `I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on contentURL.` Does that mean that the debugger stops on the assignment?

Comment: I'm sorry, not on the assignment, when I try to print it in NSLog

Comment: Using your code, I can only suspect that the variable `name` is the problem.  Can I see its definition and where you are assigning it a value?  Also, might you be using Manual Reference Counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a while ago.

Turns out that some of the block-based enumeration methods wrap the enumeration in an autorelease pool. Since you're assigning an autoreleased object, it gets deallocated before `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` returns.

(I ran into the problem with `-[NSDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`, but the same principle applies here)

Try this instead:

```
contentURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[(NSDictionary *)obj objectForKey:@"Content"];
```

Out of interest, are you using ARC? If you are, I'd have expected it to add in a `-retain` on assignment.

**Edit:** 
You are using ARC, so this isn't the answer to your question. Assigning to a __block variable will retain the object (unless you've encountered a bug in ARC, which is unlikely. The code you've provided doesn't have this issue when compiled using Apple LLVM 5.0).

It is likely that your problem is elsewhere and changing from using the convenience constructor is just masking the problem.

Likewise, the autorelease pool set up for the duration of the enumeration is likely revealing a problem that is caused elsewhere in your code. It explains why switching to using fast enumeration seems to fix the problem, but as before it is likely just masking a problem caused elsewhere in your code.

I'll leave the answer here because the information about autorelease pools may still be relevant to people who stumble across this.

Comment: Did you mean `-[NSArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:]`?

Comment: Whoops. I ran into the problem with NSDictionary, but NSArray may do the same thing.

Comment: Turns out you're spot on about the premature deallocation issues.  Convenience constructors can be tricky.

Comment: the new allocation method fixed it. silly convenience constructors :P

Comment: Particularly nasty under ARC if you're returning by reference via an `__autoreleasing` argument.

Comment: This cannot be the right answer. If the OP is using ARC, as he says he is in the comments, it is retained on assignment to `contentURL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC, as you say you are, then the code you show cannot produce the problem you describe. You must have some problem somewhere else, or your code is not as you describe.